# Why $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\Gamma\left(n - \frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(n\right)} = e^{-\frac{1}{2}}$

Tags: gamma-function

Why is it true that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\Gamma\left(n - \frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(n\right)} = e^{-\frac{1}{2}}$$

I only know the integral definition of gamma function. My notes writes
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\Gamma\left(n - \frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(n\right)}  = \lim_n\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1 - \frac{1/2}{k}\right) = e^{-1/2}$$

I don't know why the first equality holds, nor why the second equality holds...

Comment: The second equality definitely does not hold. $\sum_k \frac{1}{2k} = +\infty \implies \prod_{k=1}^\infty (1-\frac{1}{2k}) = 0$

Comment: Is it even true? W.A. seems to say otherwise (although I know WA isn't always correct): http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+of+gamma(n-0.5)%2Fgamma(n)

Comment: @Brenton I am not sure, to be honest. This note could be wrong. Anyway, I still need to evaluate the limit but not sure how to. My guess was that the limit would be $1$ (both $\Gamma(n-1/2)$ and $\Gamma(n)$ grows at similar rate?) but don't know if it's true or not.

Comment: As for why you should expect it to be zero: what is the limit of $(n - 1)! / n!$? (Then you can compare $ \frac{ \Gamma( n - 1/2 - 1/2) }{ \Gamma(n - 1/2) }  \frac{ \Gamma( n - 1/2) }{ \Gamma(n)}= \Gamma(n - 1)/\Gamma(n) = (n-2)!/(n-1)!$, which you can turn into a proof, provided you can argue that the limit exists...)

Comment: To get some intuition, notice that $$\frac{\Gamma(n-k)}{\Gamma(n)}=\frac{1}{(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-k)}\sim \frac{1}{n^k}\quad\text{as }n\to\infty$$ for each positive integer $k$. So we can expect that a similar behavior persists for non-integral $k$. Indeed, this extrapolation is justified by the Stirling's approximation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not true. If it were true, we'd have

\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\Gamma\left(n-1\right)}{\Gamma(n)}
&=&
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{\Gamma\left(n-\frac12\right)}{\Gamma(n)}\cdot\frac{\Gamma(n-1)}{\Gamma\left(n-\frac12\right)}\right)
\\
&=&
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\Gamma\left(n-\frac12\right)}{\Gamma(n)}\cdot\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\Gamma(n-1)}{\Gamma\left(n-\frac12\right)}
\\
&=&
\mathrm e^{-\frac12}\cdot\mathrm e^{-\frac12}
\\
&=&
\mathrm e^{-1}\;,
\end{eqnarray*}

whereas this limit is in fact $0$ (since the quotient is $\frac1{n-1}$).

The correct statement that this might be intended to state might be

$$
\frac{\Gamma\left(n-\frac12\right)}{\Gamma(n)}\sim n^{-\frac12}\;.
$$

Comment: May I ask how do you get the third equal sign (How to evaluate those two limits)? If it's approximately $\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}$ then wouldn't it goes to zero as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: @3x89g2: Indeed. It's a [proof by contradiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction). It assumes the OP's false claim in order to disprove it by deriving.a contradiction from it. It's prefaced with: "This is not true. If it were true, we'd have ...". The third equals sign uses the OP's false claim twice (once directly, once shifted).

Comment: Ah right... I misread. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the general case$$f_a=\frac{\Gamma (n-a)}{\Gamma (n)}\implies \log(f_a)=\log (\Gamma (n-a))-\log (\Gamma (n))$$ and use Stirling approximation to get
$$\log(f_a)=-a \log \left({n}\right)+\frac{a(a+1)}{2
   n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ Continuing with Taylor series
$$f_a=e^{\log(f_a)}=n^{-a} \left(1+\frac{a(a+1)}{2
   n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right) \right)$$

Answer (score 0):

The first equality is not true reads the comments.

for the second equality cannot be true

note that by telescopic sum we have

$$ \ln\left(\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1 - \frac{1/2}{k}\right)\right) = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\ln\left(2k - 1\right)-\ln\left(2k \right)=  \sum_{j=2}^{2n-2}\ln\left(j- 1\right)-\ln\left(j \right)\\ =  \ln\left(2- 1\right)-\ln\left(2n-2 \right)\to-\infty $$

Whence

$$\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1 - \frac{1/2}{k}\right) \to0.$$

Comment: Your summation index change isn't valid. In

$$  \sum_{k=2}^{2n-2}\ln\left(j- 1\right)-\ln\left(j \right)$$

you probably meant the summation index to be $j$ rather than $k$; but that sum isn't equal to the previous one; you now have twice as many terms.

Comment: Also, the first equation is **not** true. $\Gamma\left(n-\frac12\right)$ isn't a product of $n$ factors of the form $k-\frac12$, as appears to be assumed in that equation.